# Where's my question

Tags: support, specific-question

Some time ago I asked a question, It was located here

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2707/help-identifying-a-nes-racing-and-shooting-game

now I get a 404 and the question is not listed in my user. What happened here?

Comment: It was removed by a moderator, take a look at this meta question for a possible explanation: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1982/when-can-we-declare-an-identify-this-question-game-abandoned-and-what-should-be

Comment: But the question had answers, just not the exact one, but some people had put their tire there... And I was using the answers to look for and play games that at least where similar to the one I'm looking for.

Answer (score 11):

So let me try to explain what happened.

You created the question in July, you edited it in August, but it really didn't get much attention after that.  In fact, you didn't even participate any time in the next 6 months after asking it.  At some point we had to consider the question abandoned... unanswerable.

Unanswerable questions are Bad™.  They mean that anyone searching for that question gets superfluous results, they mean that our site looks less helpful, they mean that our signal to noise ratio decreases.  They're like ghost towns on the internet, accumulating cruft.

We **really** don't want unanswerable questions.

Ideally we don't want unanswered questions either, but as long as a question is answerable, there is hope it might one day be answered.  Honestly, it looked like you had abandoned the question and in the case of ITG, that makes it unanswerable.  So, as part of our new policy, [Abandoned ITG for over a month are deleted](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1982/when-can-we-declare-an-identify-this-question-game-abandoned-and-what-should-be/1988#1988).

This is what happened and why your question is now gone.

---

I'd also like to take the time to focus on something else you said:

> And I was using the answers to look for and play games that at least where similar to the one I'm looking for

We *really* don't want that.  We had a very long, very drawn out, fight over the policy of Game-Rec (using questions to find new games) and ultimately we had it removed from our site.  If you are using an ITG as a Game-Rec you are flouting our rules and undermining our system.  I think you can understand why that might be a bad thing.  On numerous occasions people have suggested that we ban ITG altogether because of this kind of abuse and you're just adding fuel to that fire.

Please do not do this.

Comment: I didn't did this on purpose, I wasn't expecting to someone to post a list of 100+ games, it simply happened. And I didn't abandoned the site, I get into but since I'm not too much of a player I don't have too much to answer to other people's questions.

Comment: @Disintegrator I'm not trying to accuse you (or blame you) and if it came off that way I'm sorry.  I was trying to give you things from our perspective.  From our perspective you left.  We didn't know you were lurking.  But how about this.  How about you spend some time getting involved in the community, asking questions about whatever game you're playing now, hanging out in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35) and in a couple months you try your ITG again?  by then we'll know you won't abandon it because you'll be part of the community.

Answer (score 0):

The 404 page explains:

[image]

> This question was removed from Gaming - Stack Exchange for reasons of moderation. Please refer to the FAQ for possible explanations why a question might be removed.