# My question has been removed for no apparent reason

Tags: discussion, questions

Ok, investigating a bit I found that an ITG question is removed if it [scores less than 0](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3434/why-was-my-identify-this-game-question-removed), is [not accepted over a month](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1982/when-can-we-declare-an-identify-this-question-game-abandoned-and-what-should-be/1988#1988), has [no activity for a long period of time](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2013/wheres-my-question), is not useful...

Supposing [my question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/50081/old-racing-multiplayer-browser-game-with-weapons/50991) was removed because of this (I'm not 100% sure, nobody gave me a reason), the question **was accepted**, had **4 answers**, **scored more than 1** of course, **gave a bounty** of +50, **[followed the guidelines](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)**, **I participated** several times in ALL of the answers and the question; even the answers where helpful to me as I wanted to try some of the other games they proposed, or for other people to try the game I'm asking for.

But I just find It `has been removed`. No explaining why, no apparent reason, **no possibility to check it again**...

I mean, if it's bad for stackexchange's query, just tag it as `removed` and don't list it, but PLEASE, PLEASE let us check them somehow (particularly if I'm the owner!)

I know my suggestions are not that worth, I'm not a moderator nor work here, but I don't think this is the right way to *fix it*. You need to give people a way to express themselves, [it's a fact](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/) that we need to ask this questions. Don't just say '*this is bad for the site*', and make it so we're not *banned*...

Thanks

Comment: Relevant (declined) request on MSO: [Show all of my question/answers to me even if they are deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted). Also, FWIW, here's the current [10k-vision version](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fAfla.png) of your question.

Comment: where did you get it from? Still I cannot follow the links XD

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Identify this game questions are now prohibited on the site, and are in the process of being removed.  This policy supersedes other policies that were in place previously.

This is the result of a long community discussion, which first began in November, 2010, with the final vote concluding yesterday:

[What should be done with questions asking for game identification?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4168/what-should-be-done-with-questions-asking-for-game-identification)

You can follow the discussion by checking the various links on that page.

The [FAQ](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq) has been updated to reflect this policy change.  I have also added notices to the other meta questions you referenced to prevent further confusion.

Comment: 34 vs 27 votes (56% - 44%). I still think it's not the right way to fix this...

Comment: @Nacho, the community votes and determines the fate of controversial issues such as this.  It's the only method we have of solving these kinds of issues.  I'm sorry that in this case the results were unsatisfactory from your perspective.

Comment: @Nacho It's ok.  In 3 or 4 months bring it up again and keep asking until you can get it reinstated.  It worked for the "no" votes.

Comment: I don't think the problem is so much as the change in the rules, but the lack of communication about the change. I don't think there was any visible sign of the amendment (unlike the mod elections), and surely removing a large number of questions from the site should've merited some formal notice to people who don't frequent meta.gaming? (I mean, I didn't notice until _ten days after the change_, and only because I came across what appeared to be a  closed ITG question.)

Comment: @Gwen, Meta's how we make decisions, and it's important to keep up to date with what's [featured](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/featured) on Meta (which also shows up down the right hand side of questions on the main site).  The ITG discussion was featured this way for several consecutive weeks as the decision was being made.  We also frequently discuss policy on the chat system, and even if you just drop in for a few minutes you can get caught up by looking at the "pinned" list down the right hand side.

Comment: @agent86, The problem with that is I am never on the home page of GSE (which is where the links to Meta discussion are featured) because my bookmark goes to a tag (which only has related tags on the sidebar), and my next go-to is the questions tab (which also only has tags) (and visiting a question only gives related questions). I guess I am just suggesting that if mod elections merited the pop up, rule changes should too?