# Where do we stand on Mod Identification Questions?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, game-modifications

Not too long ago, a question was asked to identify a mod in Minecraft: [Can someone help me find this Minecraft mod name?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/400071/can-someone-help-me-find-this-minecraft-mod-name)

There is a ten year old meta question about Mod Identification: [Mod Identification Questions](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4006/mod-identification-questions)

But it's not very clear from this post where the stance of *Mod Identification* stands (it seems like the original question was more of a recommendation question than a mod identification question).

We don't have a [mod-identification](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mod-identification) tag, and the question was edited by a user to add the [game-identification](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-identification) tag, which seems incorrect to me since its not asking for a game to be identified.

Thus, **where do we stand on Mod Identification questions?**

Comment: I've added [[tag:mod-identification]] and wrote a tag wiki in accordance with the [current top-voted answer](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16610/4797).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would put down with the same rules as [game-identification](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-identification).

We can't really do anything with a loose description from memory. But if you can name major elements, or provide screenshots/artifacts of key elements, then sure.

Comment: "if you can name major elements.." -> Without screenshots or media, wouldn't that fall under the off-topic criteria for "not from a description of what you can recall from memory"?

Comment: That line moves and is blurry to begin with. I'd say the definition of the line is more is there enough information that it could be only a very short list of mods/games and not a description that could apply to a crazy number of games like a semi-common game mechanic.

Comment: Not that we get many mod identification questions, but I don't think we should allow anything from memory only, just as we do for game identification.  There are TONS of Minecraft mods (which is probably the main game we'd get this kind of question for), but there are plenty other mods for others games as well (Fallout games and Skyrim come to mind).

Comment: The other problem is that, at least in the Skyrim community, it is extremely common to have three or four mods that do basically the same thing, because nobody likes to share.