# Should we allow questions asking to identify non-game elements in games?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Here is a thing. Look at the thing. Do you see the thing? I would like to know what this Thing is Called.” A plea for sanity](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5081/here-is-a-thing-look-at-the-thing-do-you-see-the-thing-i-would-like-to-know)

Last night in chat we had a spirited discussion about whether to allow questions that ask to identify elements of a game that do not directly relate to gameplay or story, such as fonts or songs. This was prompted mainly by [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/76720/what-is-the-font-used-in-pokemon-conquest), but questions such as [this one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/23300/who-sings-the-portal-2-song-want-you-gone-by-jonathan-coulton) about Portal 2 were also brought up.

It should be noted that this is about a subset of the questions LessPop_MoreFizz discussed in [his recent question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5081/here-is-a-thing-look-at-the-thing-do-you-see-the-thing-i-would-like-to-know). This is not a duplicate of that question because people presented other arguments for the removal of non-game element identification questions.

So, should we consider such questions to be on-topic on this site?

Comment: To be honest, this is a duplicate. People over-focused on the examples I cited, which had other issues. The point I made still stands, and I don't see that we need a separate discussion on the issue.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz I disagree. I read the argument in your question as "identify-this-other-thing questions do not have the same problems ITG has, and so should not be thrown out with ITG", and that doesn't address other possible problems with a subset of those questions. Plus, there seemed to be substantial disagreement in chat, with arguments that your question did not cover.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Then users can bring those up in the other question. I agree with LessPop, this is a duplicate.