# I don't have a screenshot, but would sanity check an ITG question

Tags: discussion, support

After reading [these](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5081/here-is-a-thing-look-at-the-thing-do-you-see-the-thing-i-would-like-to-know) [two](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5128/revisiting-the-identify-this-game-ban) thorough questions about rationales behind off and on topic ITG questions, I would still like to have a sanity check because the criterions I have in mind do not appear in them.

I would like to find a game (obviously) and do not have any video, audio or screenshot, **but**, I specifically know the os on which it was played, which happen to be a very unusual one for games, probably limiting the possibilities, as well as a pretty narrow time interval in which the game have been played.

Whould those be enough to ask a question about identifying a game, or should I continue banging my head at google's door?

Comment: While they're off-topic, we do have [this blog post](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2012/08/identifying-games-when-you-cant-remember-the-name/) that will helpfully lead you somewhere you can get your answers

Comment: damnit... now I wish I knew which game I was thinking about when writing that question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

There are two different kinds of problems that get the ITG label.

If you remember stuff about a game you played in the past, and want to figure out what it was, that is *blanket off topic*.

If you see a screenshot or a video of a game and want to know what it is, because it looked cool or whatever and you want to try it, that is *perfectly fine, as long as you provide the artifact*.

A caveat, while we're here. If someone asks the first kind of question, it is *not useful* to tell the person that they need an artifact in order to ask an ITG question. A person asking the first kind of question *does not have an artifact*; if they did, they'd be asking a completely different question. By even mentioning that they need an artifact, you would be misleading them into thinking that our policies are inane, becuase how could you possibly have an artifact in that case.

tl;dr: No amount of detail makes the first kind of question (the kind that you have) ok. You could try [/r/tipofmytongue](https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/). There might be an even more specific one for video games, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: oh well... thanks for being clear :p

Comment: It sounds harsh, but it really avoids a lot of useless questions and tons of equally useless answers.  Without artifacts we're literally just spewing out random nonsense here and there just to see if it triggers your memories.