# What will be our custom off-topic close reasons?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, closing

Yes! Custom close-reasons are now a thing that is coming fast to our site! Among with other important changes to <s>closing</s> putting questions on hold. Start here:

### [Closing changes: [on hold], unclear, too broad, opinion-based, off-topic reasons, bye-bye to Too Localized](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184154/162704)

Those changes aren't *yet* live on Arqade, but they'll soon be. And just as soon, we'll get to customize the off-topic close reasons. This what SE came up with on MSO:

> [image]
>
> [image: enter link description here]

In other words, we'll use this to enumerate our blanket questions bans, perhaps with an explanatory link and tips on how to fix them if possible. To my recollection our blanket question bans are about:

- Game recommendation
- Game identification *without* concrete elements (a.k.a. identify-this-game)
- Lore questions *without* supporting canon
- Piracy and support thereof
- Speculation about unreleased games
- Game design ("Why did they do it like X?" a.k.a. ask the devs)
- Multiplayer cheating which violates a games end user agreement.

Where do you come in? Well, those close reason aren't gonna write themselves! SE team will have to okay our entries, but our destiny is mostly in our hands. Plus, I might've missed something.

Some things to keep in mind to make everybody's life easier:

- **Make it simple.** New users will be reading those and they won't be used to our lingo.
- **Make it solid.** Avoid using expressions that could be used as an (invalid) retort to the close reason: don't say we require something concrete or else the question is guesswork/unclear/unhelpful/who cares; just say we require something concrete period. We can explain if asked.
- **Make it short.** There's no need to write a treaty. The limit is 500 characters of markdown (links count!).
- **Make it need-to-know.** Linking to meta is only helpful so far as it helps users drag the question into the realms of acceptability. There's simply *no need* to point a new user to the eleventy bajillion questions on meta and discussion on chat we've had about game-rec. Want to point to [LessPop's treaty on acceptable game identification](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5081/here-is-a-thing-look-at-the-thing-do-you-see-the-thing-i-would-like-to-know)? That's more useful.
- **Make it three.** [Apparently](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7295/what-will-be-our-custom-off-topic-close-reasons/7298#comment20259_7295) three close reasons is all we get, at least at the beginning.

Comment: "Confuses @badp"

Comment: Also game dev.  I think "Collections" fall under recommendations but the full reason would probably need to make it clear.  [http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @MatthewRead I'd kinda rather game-dev close reasons would actually be migrate-to-game-dev close reasons rather than just OT close reasons, but sure, let's add that too.

Comment: You might find [this](http://data.stackexchange.com/gaming/query/119700/a-sampling-of-recent-off-topic-and-too-localized-closures) useful... Also, try to focus on the *most* important reasons, as the number of available slots is limited (to three, at least initially).

Comment: We don't need a "piracy" close reason, this is already covered by the off topic close reason and is specifically mentioned in /help

Comment: @kali That's why I deleted http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/7297/23

Comment: @kalina The blanket 'off topic' close reason is going away. Going forward, questions will be Off Topic->Reason 1, Off Topic-> Reason 2, Off Topic ->Reason 3, or Off Topic -> Custom Text. Ideally, all 3 of our custom close reasons will be covered in /help. That doesn't obviate the need for them.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz mmk

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'll take a crack.

1. Questions that ask which games or other products meet specific criteria are off topic. We primarily deal with questions about playing games, not about which games to play or historical trivia. We make an exception for identifying games based on [an audiovisual artifact from the game in question.](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5081/here-is-a-thing-look-at-the-thing-do-you-see-the-thing-i-would-like-to-know)
2. Questions about unreleased or illegal content are off topic on Arqade. We only support questions about games available to the general public through legitimate means.
3. Questions about Game Design and Development are off topic. This includes speculative questions about developer intent, as well as lore questions not addressed directly through in-game sources.

Comment: These could probably be improved with some appropriate meta links, but I'm lazy, so I figure if they aren't terrible, someone will come along and edit them in for me. Because you guys are awesome like that, and less lazy than I am.

Comment: +1! Though I think I agree with @badp that #3 can simply be handled by the mods with off-topic-> migration

Comment: This looks good, one thing I thought of while reading this is I am not sure 2. explains if discussing betas is on topic (i.e public betas like diablo 3 had), not sure if this could cause some confusion.

Comment: @SimonL A link to a meta post would probably help on that front.

Comment: @RavenDreamer I have to *strongly* disagree that #3 is solvable by migration. The *vast majority* of our 'game dev' questions are **not** strong candidates for migration. They are often rants poorly disguised as questions asking 'why does [MECHANIC] work like this' - they're better off being simply closed outright.

Comment: I kinda liked badp's idea of linking to external sites that would take the question in the close reason. It seems like a good way to be nice to the user.

Comment: #2 is kinda wrong, private betas are okay

Comment: @badp That just depends on your definition of 'general public'. We allow questions about private betas for which are actually invitation-only public betas. We don't allow questions about true private betas, where the only way to be a tester is to be friends with someone who works for the developer.

Comment: Fantastic work combining the reasons into categories that make sense.

Comment: Do we want to broaden number one to include other types of "list questions"?  People sometimes like to argue that those aren't identification or recommendation, they just want a list of all games with multi-player support for the 3DS.

Comment: @bwarner I think the new 'Too Broad' will handle those well enough.

Comment: I don't like to put illegal and unreleased content into the same close reasons, those are two fundamentally different reasons and this will likely cause issues when questions about unreleased content are closed, and the users see the word "illegal".

Comment: `"Questions about which games or other products meet specific criteria are off topic."` I think this could use some massaging.  It just feels a little off when reading it.

Comment: @MBraedley I'm open to suggestions! That's the result of a bunch of iterating, but it could definitely use some more!

Comment: @MadScient unfortunately, we only get to have 3 for now. However, I think the synthesis of the two works *great*. Nice job, LessPop.

Comment: Maybe 2 can be reversed so that the "general public only" part comes before the "unreleased or illegal" part? Or does the off-topic part have to come first?

Comment: @Toomai It was explained to me that the syntax I've used (X is Off Topic. More Details, more details) is 'preferred, but not required', which I infer to mean "You don't have to do it this way, but you ought to have a damn good reason not to."

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz: I think it's as simple as changing it from "Questions about which games..." to "Questions that ask which games...".  Don't know why that took me 2 days to figure out.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz and Raven: For #3:  questions about game design/development should be migrated to gamedev, but questions about the design/development of **a specific game** should just be closed as off topic.  So maybe instead of "Game Design and Development" as the close-reason, we could say something more along the lines of "game-design decisions for specific games" or "game design intentions," or something?

Comment: @BlueRaja I'm not sure that's necessary. When a question is placed **On Hold**, that's a status that indicates that it's awaiting some sort of *action*. Sometimes, the appropriate action is an edit from OP. Sometimes, it's migration. Sometimes it's closure and deletion. I'm not sure what we *gain* by requiring close voters to flag an open question or use custom text or a not-quite-perfect-anymore-because-we-made-it-too-specific close reason just to get an off topic question placed on hold until someone is able to act on it.

Comment: Who said anything about placing a question on hold?  Either it would be migrated or it would be closed, depending on the topic.

Comment: @Blueraja read the linked MSO post in the Op.

Comment: These close reasons are a go.

Answer (score 6):

1. Questions asking us to suggest or recognize a game are off topic, unless you have something concrete like a screenshot or a piece of soundtrack to identify. Otherwise, Reddit can help with [suggestions](http://www.reddit.com/r/gamingsuggestions) and [identification](http://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue), while Wikipedia can help with [videogame categories.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Video_games)
2. Questions about unreleased games or updates are off topic.  We are not a news site. [Maybe Wikipedia can help?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Upcoming_video_games)
3. Questions about the lore of a videogame series are off-topic if the answer is not covered by its canon. We believe that is the case here; please comment with evidence if you believe otherwise.

Comment: Not sure If I'm satisfied with the wording, but these are the big three, I think.

Comment: Maybe "suggest or identify" or "suggest or remember" rather than "suggest or recognize". I don't think "recognize" is the right word.

Comment: #3 is really unclear about how fuzzy our line is with lore questions. I'd rather just close the bad ones as 'too broad' or 'primarily opinion based' and use that close reason to deal with piracy or gamedev questions.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz I believe [what I've written _is_ our line with lore questions precisely.](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/2293/23)

Comment: @StrixVaria "recognize" was edited in, the original word was "pick."

Comment: @badp I recognize that. And I still think that language is just too goddamned fuzzy. It's part of why I hate dealing with lore questions in general. :P

Comment: The problem with the current wording of #1 is that it implies that game rec is on-topic so long as they provide a screenshot/song from a game they like. Rolling these two together is a good idea though, if the logical scope can be ironed out.

Answer (score -2):

I like badp's #2, and LessPopMoreFizz's number #3, but I'd like to give my own take on number #1

1: **Game Identification/Recommendation**

> Requests for game recommendations are off-topic - they are not a good fit for our Q&A model - as they cannot be objectively answered and tend to promote lengthy discussions. Requests for identification are only permitted when accompanied with an audio-visual clue, such as a screenshot or piece of music.

Comment: Your description of recommendations doesn't seem correct to me.  Recommendations are normally short and off-hand.

Comment: @MatthewRead - "Which is the best game/console/graphics card/blork for me" is the recommendations I see most often, and they cannot be objectively answered, hence "lengthy discussions". I've edited it a little bit, added the part about them not being objective

Comment: Eh, the way you've written this mainly covers those questions which could be closed using the new **Primarily Opinion Based** close reason, and completely fails to address all the other list/catalog/what was the first game/what are all the games with feature/etc. questions.

Answer (score -2):

Questions that ask us to help with any form of multiplayer cheating, whether it be pirating or hacking are considered to be off topic on Arqade. Perhaps Reddit can help with that?

Comment: This isn't necessarily true. Asking about cheating in single player games can be perfectly fine. For example, some consider using the console in Skyrim "cheating".

Comment: @StrixVaria added the word multiplayer.

Comment: I wouldn't want to include an offsite resource link - even to a site as innocuous as reddit - for any sort of illicit activity, no matter how minor or benign. It sends the wrong message, IMO.