# Idenfity-this-game close reason

Tags: support, status-completed, closing

I could have sworn there was a close reason for identify-this-game type questions, but I can't see it now.

Should I place a custom close reason on these questions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We are currently in the process of ironing out a [fourth close reason](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8082/are-there-grounds-for-getting-an-extra-custom-reason-close-slot). The close reasons were clunky before, with too much being put into each one. The fourth one will make that better, but until that is finished, we don't have a close reason for ITG.

Comment: So for the moment, use a custom close reason.

Comment: And it's done..