# Links in "Questions asking for help identifying a game" close reason are broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, hyperlinks

There is a "Questions asking for help identifying a game" close reason when flagging:

> [image: Flag -> Closing -> Off-topic modal box]

Both links are broken, leading to a 404 error page. The first one (the blog) is http://blog.arqade.com/2012/08/i, which redirects to https://gaming.stackexchange.com//2012/08/i and reports 404 Not Found.

The second link points to ["Here is a thing. Look at the thing. Do you see the thing? I would like to know what this Thing is Called." A plea for sanity](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5081) which redirects (for some weird reason) to https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5074/help-identify-old-coin-op-arcade-game/5081#5081, that was removed by moderators or high rep users of the site.

Can the links be fixed please? Correct links are:

- `http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2012/08/i`
- `http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/5081`

(looks like arqade.com is broken or expired)

Comment: also http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8692/arqade-com-blog-arqade-com-and-meta-arqade-com-are-broken

Comment: @3ventic great, never thought to search here - thanks! :-)