# Is it on topic to ask "help me remember this game?"

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I have a computer game I played in the 90s that I can't remember the name of and am having trouble Googling.

Is it on topic to post the details I do remember and ask if anyone knows the name of it?

Comment: To the down voter: this is a valid question. Would you prefer I just asked about the game on the main site? (Unless this is a duplicate in which case I apologize)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Questions asking for help **identifying a game**, whether based on a description, or feature list, or any other set of criteria (i.e. "What was the first game to…") are off-topic; [this blog post](http://blog.arqade.com/2012/08/i) might help. We allow an exception for identifying games based on [an actual piece of the game, such as screenshots or audio clips.](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5081)

Comment: Thank you. Clearly my original question must be a duplicate. Thank you for taking the time to answer it anyway :)

Comment: It should be noted though that these artefacts *need* to be actually from the game. Hand drawn images and voice clips of you copying the music or sound effects don't count. (Yes we have had this happen)