# Multiple questions within one question

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I'm specifically referring to this question:

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/240067/vac-banned-in-csgo-but-not-vac-banned-in-steam-profile-or-any-other-game

Now this question seems to be asking more than one question with a volume of information which could be referring to either of thee stated questions.

These three questions are about VAC but they are in different sub-categories

> Is he really VAC banned?

Asking a question about how another company issued a ban to another user

> Are VAC labels really delayed? (I've heard sources that it's immediate)

Asking how the other companies ban system works and items on the other companies interface

> Is this a bug? (Being that the servers think he's banned even though he isn't?)

Asking if another companies system is bugged

This type of question I think should come under the "too broad" category but apparently doesn't, even though it's asking three different questions which would require a decent screed of explaining for each question.

Also you DO NOT require gaming experience to specify an answer for this question, like you DO NOT need gaming experience to identify a font, or identify a piece of music.

**Quote from another post and well known user on the site:**

"Is figuring out which font a game uses something that's in a gamer's skillset?"

Now many agreed with this, if we replace "font" with something similar referring to the above discussion, it it within the gamers skillset to do this?

[Is font identification really a gaming skill?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10947/is-font-identification-really-a-gaming-skill)

User : Frank

Comment: I have no idea what the font thing has to do with this, other than "is this a gamer thing that we should know" - I think we have a better chance knowing about how gaming related systems work than fonts which are more a designer thing.

Comment: It's about steam which I think we've classified as on topic in some meta post somewhere as it's a gaming system so gamers will know the most about it. As for the multiple questions I'd say it's fine because they're all related and essentially they're asking "what's going on?" the three questions are really just possibilities that OP thinks may be what's going on.

Comment: @Aequitas, from my point of view, OPs questions are all answerable "in one go", but rely on if the user account actually is banned, or if there is a bug going around. Ultimately, a potential answer to the later would cover all three questions, and still fall within our expertise; However, if it comes down to "is this user really banned", I fail to see how any of us could determine any more then what OP has already provided, without directly asking Steam

Comment: @Timelord64 delete your answer that's right... and I was firstly talking about whether we should allow multiple questions in one questions the second part should have been another discussion on whether or not that question was actually genuine for this sites criteria

Comment: @Timelord64 also Matt, why did you delete your question

Comment: In other words, the two are unrelated, so by your argument they should be in separate discussion forms. I remove my own content as it becomes invalid, or serves its purpose. Keep in mind, lower-rep users can not see my answer, but high-reps can. It is now unclear to me what you are actually asking, and therefore I can't answer. This is not a discussion board, so I will delete content as I believe it becomes invalid.

Comment: @Timelord64 this is not a discussions board, -_-, there's a discussion tag

Comment: I think the point you raise about font is flaky - the voting on it is currently very contentious, with both top-voted answers being equally voted on despite leaning in opposite directions. Jason Berkan also raises [an excellent point](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10947/is-font-identification-really-a-gaming-skill#comment33703_10947) in the comments there: *"Regardless of whether font identifications are allowed or not, I am not comfortable with "gaming expertise / gamer's skillset" being used as the threshold for allowed questions. It is too open to interpretation."*

Comment: As somewhat of a sidenote: you're losing focus with your question.  You have at least two different arguments going on, but haven't really connected the two.  That said, Steam is *categorically* on-topic.  So if you're looking at making the argument that Steam related tech like VAC bans is off-topic, you're going to run into some major resistance.  See [here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6890/why-are-steam-questions-on-topic/6895#6895).

Comment: @Timelord64 I posted this before that user did? So it's the duplicate

Comment: @Foxhound, I can see how you would interpret it that way. We do not use time as a measure for which is the duplicate, we use quality. If a question is posted now, and recieves much more attention, has higher quality, higher votes, better answers, etc. then a question from over a year ago, the older question is considered the duplicate. TLDR; we want to push users to the best question, not the first in.

Comment: @Foxhound, aplogies for the lack of effort, as I am just about to go out. Ironically, [this question](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10722/duplicate-mistake) is a duplicate of the meta I usually reference. They come to the same conclusion.

Comment: The other question has a score of +7, as opposed to the -5, here. The other question has an accepted answer with a score of 19 (from a mod, which to me strengthens the reliability), where this question has no accepted answers, an answer of +2, and an answer of -2. I have since retracted my answer of -2, as I was since confused if that was even the question you were intending to ask.

Comment: Keep in mind that answers can be merged into the "official question" from duplicates, to retain quality of answers, aswell.

Answer (score 1):

> These three questions are about VAC but they are in different sub-categories

I haven't examined the previous edits to the original question, but as it stands now, the question seems to have a well defined scope.  It is regarding a scenario where a user is being told they are VAC banned from a specific game, but are able to access other games.  When I read the question in its current form I can see they are asking if the behaviour is correct or a bug.

Yes, the question is technically asking multiple questions.  However, if you read between the lines you can see that they are speculating answers.  This approach is generally common when someone asks a question about something they feel doesn't adhere to known/common rules.  "Is that right?... shouldn't it do this?... why is it doing this instead?..." etc.

An answer should try to address the concerns.  For example, in this case perhaps the assumption that a VAC ban affects all VAC games doesn't apply, or is perhaps delayed.

> Also you DO NOT require gaming experience to specify an answer for this question

Technically, you don't actually need in game experience for a lot of questions.  There are so many FAQ/Wiki sites around that you can pull together answers to questions that way.  However, you can also answer these questions with in-game knowledge.

In fact, if you are a user of Steam you may have:

1. Been banned before so can give your direct experiences
2. A user on your friends list who is banned so can tell you if they see the same behaviour

> like you DO NOT need gaming experience to identify a font, or identify a piece of music.

The font question still appears up for discussion.  There are a number of different answers with up votes.  My answer is currently leading, but doesn't even commit to yes or no.  I didn't think that the validity of music identification was being questioned (obviously, as long as it is in game).

The font problem is actually specific to the skills needed to identify a font, rather than having experience with the Steam platform.  The link with the font question would be stronger if the source question asked "I can has VAC ban?" with a picture of a TF2 cat hat.

**Comment on source question status**

I don't actually agree that the source question should be closed.  The problem is clearly defined.  Someone with a similar experience in being banned can provide an answer (whether to confirm they have the same behaviour, or otherwise).