# Can we block certain users?

Tags: discussion, support, questions

I feel as though I am being constantly pulled down by a certain other user, not naming names.

I'm beginning to actually feel agitated and less attracted to the site because I know if I post something it'll attract this users attention

The user will post comments which aren't needed and also edit somethings I don't want edit, all because of his higher rep

Fair enough some of the comments and edits are correct but most seem to be annoying pointless things and I want to do something about it to return to enjoying my experience on the site

Comment: There's no way to block or prevent other users from interacting with you or your posts on the site.  You can *ignore* messages by individual users in chat, but on the main site you're unfortunately going to have to put up with it.

Comment: Trust me, unless it's outright rude or attacking you directly (which **should** be raised if it is!) - the user is probably primarily concerned with raising the quality of the post and is not trying to pull you down :). It *can* feel like it, because they are *your* posts therefore you feel a sense of ownership over it, and it definitely stings a bit when they critique it. I ran into a similar issue, where I was the guy inadvertently doing this, see here: [I seem to have painted a target on my back](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/7318/28182)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you mean ignoring them in chat, then yes, that is a possibility. If you mean ignoring them on the site, that's not possible.

If you notice comments that are unfriendly/offtopic/rude etc, flag them and a moderator will take a look.

As for the edits, this site is all about collaboration. The people who can edit without needing to get it approved have earned that reputation on the site, and thus are trusted to be able to make edits that don't change the intent of the question, merely improve it to be better within our guidelines. Sometimes these edits might just be minor things like grammar, but trust that the people with these privileges have worked to get to the point where effectively the community trusts them to do what is right.

That said, if you notice edits that change your intent or are otherwise rude/abusive, please flag the post with a custom flag explaining why it needs another set of eyes, and one of us moderators will be able to take a look at it for you. You also have the ability to roll back edits on your own posts, if you really think they are changing the intent of the post. Keep in mind we tend to regularly edit out things like greetings or thank yous, as they're not necessary.

In general, we all are trying to make the internet more awesome, and part of that is realizing that yes, they're your questions that you asked, but the whole point of the network is to provide a resource for the internet as a whole. We try to, like I've said, keep things in line with the OP's intent, but sometimes we just have to clean things up or tweak things or add additional information from clarifying comments, or add tags, the list goes on.

So basically, this is a long winded way of saying "no, you can't ignore people on main sites" while also maybe explaining why you are seeing some of the things you are seeing.

Answer (score -5):

You can not block other users. This is not a forum, and we are not socially networking. This is a Q & A site, and we are curating each others work. I would employ you to simply raise this issue with a mod.

Since this is obviously about me, lets have a look at the two (2) times I have posted on your raised questions.

---

In the question ["Multiple Questions with one question"](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10955/multiple-questions-within-one-question) you make a very valid point. In what context do we allow multiple questions, with consideration of whether too many questions would be considered too broad. All goes well, until the end, where you add this extra piece of information.

> Also you DO NOT require gaming experience to specify an answer for this question, like you DO NOT need gaming experience to identify a font, or identify a piece of music.
>
> Quote from another post and well known user on the site:
>
> "Is figuring out which font a game uses something that's in a gamer's skillset?"
>
> Now many agreed with this, if we replace "font" with something similar referring to the above discussion, it it within the gamers skillset to do this?
>
> Is font identification really a gaming skill?
>
> User : Frank

Since your initial post, there has been question as to what font identification has to do with multiple questions;

> I have no idea what the font thing has to do with this, other than "is this a gamer thing that we should know" - I think we have a better chance knowing about how gaming related systems work than fonts which are more a designer thing. **– Ashley Nunn♦ Oct 19 at 22:23**
>
> As somewhat of a sidenote: you're losing focus with your question. You have at least two different arguments going on, but haven't really connected the two. That said, Steam is categorically on-topic. So if you're looking at making the argument that Steam related tech like VAC bans is off-topic, you're going to run into some major resistance. See here. **– Frank Oct 20 at 1:25**

and as such, I felt that removal of what appeared to be an end-of-discussion rant was pertinent to the quality of your general question. **I am also entirely within my right to delete my own answer**, especially when you tell me I have missed the point. If my answer does not answer your question, why would I leave it there to confuse other users? 10k+ users can still see it. In fact, they can even vote to override my deletion choice, if they decide it is useful.

---

In the question "[How often does foilage and gem boxes spawn](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/241195/how-often-does-foliage-spawn)", you ask about foilage and gem boxes. The gem boxes part has already been answered, [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/240833/what-causes-a-gem-box-to-spawn-in-clash-of-clans), so I voted to close as duplicate. While I get that your **intentions** was to focus on foliage, it still seemed like a pretty even double question. In fact, in writing this response, another user has voted to close as duplicate, and another user has since removed all references to the gem boxes.

---

Most comments have been defending these two very actions. So if they are "true", I'm finding it hard to see how they are "pointless".

I do sincerely apologise if you think these actions are deliberately to target you, for any reason. These have all been efforts to improve your questions, efforts that others appear to agree with. You have to remember that we have our policies, and while everyone has their own individual views on how things should be, **we are not here for ourselves. We are here for the community.**

Comment: Just they way I feel man, not going to start cussing anyone out or being childish about it. I feel like you were targeting me, just my opinion, if you are trying to help then great I accept it with open arms but sometimes it feels like there is unnecessary comments and small edits that I feel change my intent, many users have edited and commented my questions but I feel you are the only user that makes me feel dragged down, yet again just my thoughts and feelings, excuse any spelling or grammar, iPhone probs

Comment: A lesson in not taking things so personal, I guess. If I see posts as obvious as the ones you made, @Foxhound, I'm always going to make the suggested edits. If a question warrants obvious downvoting, or has an obvious duplication, or any other obvious inconsistency, I will always make the changes. In fact, I had to go through your user log to find the previous case, as I had not remembered you from previously. I had not even seen the username; The duplication was so apparent that username was irrelevant, and I simply had not read it yet.

Comment: I feel we have dissolved into discussion in the first instance, and you might have interpreted it harshly. Ultimately, this site has specific rules. If you disagree with the rules, you can raise the issue on meta. [It does not always work, but props to you for trying to set things right in how you think this site should be curated.](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10985/what-is-our-current-stance-on-spoiler-markdown-2015) At the end of the day, we have to follow the rules, **even when it goes against our opinions**.

Comment: For future endeavors, I think I might just opt for discussion rooms, if we clash on a change, on board. That might let us actually hash it out, without the need for deleting comments so the page does not get drawn out. Regardless, I would recommend you take the [tour](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour). Gives you a brief run down on what this particular site is about, and covers some of the things we had to "argue" about. It also rewards you with a nice badge :) I will try to be more conscious of you, in the future, but if you see I've edited one of your posts, don't take it personally.

Comment: fair enough dude :) I've heard you out and I see sense in what you're saying, try jumping into bridge ever so often so we can talk things over should my opinion differ from you also so you can actually just talk, you're a rising member on the site, communicate with us!