# Add prohibition of "name this mechanic/design"-style questions to the tour

Tags: feature-request, ambiguous-tags, site-faq

I asked, despite my best judgement, [a poorly received question that got intensely downvoted and closed as too broad by five people, two of which are high-profile users](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/308421/term-for-catatonic-mob-behaviour-in-mmorpgs).

I thought "name this mechanic/design"-style questions were on-topic because of [terminology](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) and a couple of questions that did just that. Also, [FAQ/Tour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) saying that questions about *"Game mechanics and terminology"* are on-topic.

However, if you read the comments to my question, you'll see seasoned answerers despise these questions and think they are off-topic.

Therefore, I suggest we should modify FAQ/Tour to:

- list questions about explaining a named mechanic and/or design as on-topic,
- list questions about identifying an unnamed mechanic and/or design as off-topic.

Comment: Is the tag's description not good enough?

Comment: related: https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11467/do-we-want-to-support-is-there-a-term-for-x-questions/11472#11472

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer In theory, yes. But most tag descriptions on most SE sites are pretty broad and questions like that are acceptable on RPG.SE's terminology tag - so this is not explicit enough. Perhaps we should add something along the lines of `DO NOT use it to ask questions about "does this thing have a name?"`, only worded better.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do we want to change our policy on "Is There a Term for X?" questions?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15942/do-we-want-to-change-our-policy-on-is-there-a-term-for-x-questions) (a more recent community consensus on the same topic)

Comment: Do we always close questions on topics that have been reviewed and revised again later on?

Comment: @joachim I think in this case we should, since if someone came across this post, the linked duplicate will guide them.

Comment: @Joachim We should, to avoid confusing users on our current policy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the tag is just fine as it is. The excerpt mentions that the tag should be used

> For questions that ask what a gaming-specific term means.

Nothing about it mentions labelling a gaming-specific *thing* with a name. Furthermore, [the tag's full info](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/terminology/info) mentions that

> It is not appropriate for repository style questions that seek to span the terminology graph.

Comment: I see your point in saying "if it doesn't say it's allowed, it's not"; I just believe it would help to be more explicit, especially since the linked questions shows it's a recurring problem.

Comment: Also, a tiny nit-pick: the quoted part in tag's full info wouldn't have helped in my case, since it asked for a specific, easily-identifiable thing that is a recurrent hallmark of virtually all titles in a single genre.

Comment: Judging by lack of any other responses, this is a majority opinion, so I'll mark this answer as accepted.