# Should we update our /help/on-topic page?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, help-center

It was recently noted by a few users that our on-topic page lacks any indication that we don't offer technical support for modded Minecraft. While the on-topic certainly doesn't need to cover everything, we close a *lot* of Minecraft questions due to this rule. So updating our [/help/on-topic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to include this makes sense to me.

However, before I go ahead and do that, I figure we might as well just review the page as a whole:

> Arqade is for passionate videogamers from all platforms, including consoles, computers, handhelds, and mobile devices. If your question
>   generally covers things such as …
>
> - Gameplay strategies and tactics
> - Puzzle solving or obstacle clearing
> - Game mechanics and terminology
> - Plot and characters in games
> - Game-specific hardware and utilities
>
> …then you are in the right place to ask your question!
>
> Please note, however, that site policies *prohibit*
>   questions of the following types:
>
> - Game and Mod Development (try the [Game Development Stack
>     Exchange](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com) instead)
> - Speculative questions about developer intent, with respect to both mechanics and narrative
> - Requests for game identification based on personal recollection alone.  See What are
>     the requirements for asking a game identification question?
> - Catalogues (listing games that fit specific criteria or are like an existing game)
> - Shopping advice and recommendations
> - Speculation of the future of the industry and of upcoming releases
> - Piracy, and support with pirated games.
>
> For more help, see ["What types of
>   questions should I avoid asking?"](/help/dont-ask)
>
> Please [look around](/search) to see if your question
>   has been asked before. It’s also OK to ask and answer your own
>   question.
>
> If your question is not specifically on-topic for Arqade, it may be
>   on topic for [another Stack
>   Exchange site](http://stackexchange.com/sites). If no site currently exists that will accept your
>   question, you may [commit
>   to](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) or propose
>   a new site at [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/),
>   the place where new Stack Exchange communities are democratically
>   created.

What changes should we make to this page, if any?

Comment: I'd probably consolidate the two speculation items in the second list, the whole section is rather large

Comment: Cheating in multiplayer games isn't mentioned anywhere either.

Comment: Is there any way to ask for "show what you have tried" on minecraft-commands questions? There are lots of questions that come here and be like "How do I do X" without anything else.

Comment: Show what you've tried shouldn't be limited to Minecraft, @Moacir. But that's not really relevant to what's on topic; that's more the behaviour we expect.

Comment: More importantly, we don't prohibit questions that show a lack of research, nor should we.  Prohibited questions are those that we are absolutely unable or unwilling to help the user answer.  We've shown that with Minecraft tech support.

Comment: From what I've seen, a majority of the questions asking for tech support on modded minecraft are by low rep, unregistered users never to be seen again. I'm curious on how many of those users actually stop to think "is this off-topic? Lemme check the help guide".

Comment: @Wondercricket At least one person did, so I think this is a good idea

Answer (score 9):

Just so we can vote on this proposal, I'm making this post in favour of listing modded Minecraft tech support as off-topic in the on-topic page.

Answer (score 7):

Building off Mad Scientist's comment, a couple of the items under the prohibit section could be combined. As it stands, it's very wordy and a few of the items are similar. The suggested wording below can be tweaked as seen fit

**Speculation**

> - Speculative questions about developer intent, with respect to both mechanics and narrative
> - Speculation of the future of the industry and of upcoming releases

These two could be combined into:

> - Speculations on future of the industry, upcoming (but unreleased) games or content, and developer intent on mechanics and narrative

**Recommendations**

> - Catalogues (listing games that fit specific criteria or are like an existing game)
> - Shopping advice and recommendations

These two could be combined into:

> - Recommendations for software, hardware, games, or genres

Comment: I agree with the speculation suggestion and would upvote if you put that separately.  I disagree that it is obvious that "listing games that fit specific criteria or are like an existing game" is the same thing as a recommendation.  I understand why you are saying that it is and agree that both are for the same reason.  I just don't think that it will be obvious to people reading the help for the first time.  Also, shopping advice includes recommendations for places to purchase and negotiating, which you have dropped.

Answer (score 0):

Suggested wording for modded Minecraft:

> Please check the tag wiki for the game about which you are asking before posting.  For example, modded [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) questions are off-topic.

This generalizes the advice slightly while still covering the specific situation of modded Minecraft.

Answer (score -2):

While at the time I said that the tag's description was enough, now seems like a good time to revisit this suggestion: [Add prohibition of "name this mechanic/design"-style questions to the tour](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12463/add-prohibition-of-name-this-mechanic-design-style-questions-to-the-tour)

I am, of course, assuming that there is a consensus on treating these questions as too broad and/or primarily opinion based. If there isn't, then the tag's info page should be changed, but that's a discussion for another time.

Answer (score -3):

I voted to close so many questions as off-topic as "it's tech support for modded Minecraft" that my phone now autocompletes it after "it's". But I only did that because it was a rule. If we now discuss the reasoning for it, I want to actually argue against it:

99% of the questions that are closed this way are covered by the "too broad" close reason anyway. People just install a hundred mods without any consideration, the game crashes and they dump the log and list of mods (if we're lucky) or just the fact that it crashed into the question box. Since the reason for the crash can be any of the mods or any combination of mods, it is actually way too broad for a question here. We could either close this as "too broad" or make an FAQ tutorial on how to debug situations like these (remove some mods, try again, if it works remove everything except the last removed one, then try some settings and so on) and close those questions as duplicate, like we already do for "is there a list of error codes for Minecraft". That would be more helpful for the askers.

So, what about the remaining 1%? These are basically already fine, but closed anyway because of the rule. For example someone only installed Optifine and the game crashed. This can be looked at pretty easily: See if you can reproduce it, if yes, can you find a solution to it, if not, ask for more information, if there's no solution, tell them to report it as an Optifine bug.

TLDR: Remove that close reason completely, close most of these questions as "too broad" instead.

Comment: "Too broad" could work, but I think it then opens up arguments about "But I only have 1 mod installed!", et cetera. PLus if we just close them all as "Too broad" then they're really just off-topic, but we're just putting them under a different close reason (aka I think it makes it less clear). That said, if you disagree, I'd suggest making a new meta question instead of trying to have a discussion on this one. We should add "Modded minecraft tech support isn't allowed" in the /help/on-topic page even if we decided to change the go-to close reason.

Comment: What would be so bad about it if they only have one mod? Then it's much easier to find the issue.

Comment: That's a fair point, but it's because of those details which I think mean your disagreement with the current policy warrants a whole new meta.