# The /help/on-topic page has been updated

Tags: discussion, help-center

As [per this meta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13390/should-we-update-our-help-on-topic-page), I've gone ahead and updated the [/help/on-topic page](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). The changes were primarily drawn from [these](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13393/8350) two [answers](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13395/8350):

Specifically, I've added text about technical support for modded minecraft being off-topic:

> - Technical support for [non-vanilla Minecraft](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10390/minecraft-crash-questions-should-be-made-off-topic-yes-no)

And I combined these four lines:

> - Speculative questions about developer intent, with respect to both mechanics and narrative
> - Speculation of the future of the industry and of upcoming releases
> - Catalogues (listing games that fit specific criteria or are like an existing game)
> - Shopping advice and recommendations

into these two lines:

> - Speculations on future of the industry, upcoming (but unreleased) games or content, and developer intent on mechanics and narrative
> - Recommendations for software, hardware, games, or genres

I've unfeatured the [other meta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13390/should-we-update-our-help-on-topic-page), but if any other popular suggested changes pop up in the next week or so I can go ahead and update the /help/on-topic page again.

Comment: The title could not be better.