# Close reason for game identification questions has dead links

Tags: bug, status-completed

Close Reason:

> This question appears to be off-topic. The users who voted to close gave this specific reason:
>
> "Questions asking for help identifying a game, whether based on a description, or feature list, or any other set of criteria are off-topic; [this blog post](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2012/08/i) might help. We allow an exception for [identifying games based on an actual piece of the game,](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5081) such as screenshots or audio clips."

Both the links seem to not be working.

- http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2012/08/i
- ["Here is a thing. Look at the thing. Do you see the thing? I would like to know what this Thing is Called." A plea for sanity](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5081)

The first one has a 404 error and the 2nd one just doesn't seem to load (maybe just for me?)

Comment: SE is in the middle of a [move to HTTPS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292058) network-wide, this is likely a symptom of that. It seems to be in a halfway place right now as forcing HTTPS on those links also gives a security warning and then a 404 again once the warning is dismissed. We can update them manually on the close reason once the links are migrated across and the secure cert warning is resolved.

Comment: Interesting that the meta.arqade.com one works if you manually redirect to meta.gaming.stackexchange.com - indicating a broken redirect

Answer (score 3):

I have adjusted the close reason to have the correct links - due to size limitations, I also had to change some of the phrasing:

> Questions asking for help identifying a game, based on a description, feature list, or any other criteria are off-topic; this [blog post](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2012/08/identifying-games-when-you-cant-remember-the-name/) might help. One exception is [identifying games based on an actual piece of the game](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5081), i.e. screenshots or audio clips.

Comment: Thanks Oded! :)