# Is it possible for the defunct Arqade blog link on the Game Identification Learn More page to be secured?

Tags: bug, game-identification, blog

On our [game-identification](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-identification) tags [Learn More page](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/game-identification/info), there is a link to a now defunct Arqade blog at the bottom of the page:

`https://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2012/08/identifying-games-when-you-cant-remember-the-name/`

Despite seeming secure (uses HTTPS), it seems the server certificate doesn't match the URL:

[image: warning]

Is this something that can be fixed? Or should we just omit this from the tag's Learn More page?

Comment: Cross-site duplicate of [The SSL certificate for the archived Stack Exchange Gaming Blog is invalid](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368976/566903)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I alluded to this issue in [Re-evaluating the text of our Game Identification close reason](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13017).

At the time, the blog post was linked in the close reason itself - not a great look having a big security warning appear from a link on a close reason - so we removed it. I placed the contents of the blog into the Game Identification Wiki, to lessen the amount of clicks to the archived blog.

While it's not great that this cert issue still exists, for the time being I've edited the Game Identification Wiki, replacing the direct link to the blog with [one from archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20210515140536/https://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2012/08/identifying-games-when-you-cant-remember-the-name/), which doesn't present the cert issue. When (if?) this cert issue ever gets solved, we can replace the link again to go directly to the blog.