# What comes first, rules or helpfulness?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, game-identification

Reading this [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/303066/cant-remember-a-name-of-a-mini-car-shooting-game), 99% of the gamers probably can figure out what the game is 2 sentences in.

I'm perfectly aware that we don't allow game identification because it would be too opinion based to guess what might be in someone's head just by a vague description (as far as I understand the rules).

So what should I do:

1. Tell him "sorry, but no" and direct him to an outside source (what Jutschge did)
2. Explain to him how he's wrong but still provide an answer (or at least a comment with the name but comments don't bring rep, hence my choice) (What I did)
3. Ignore altogether and vote close the question (strongly against my believes as a visitor and contributor to this community)

While we are at it, the two links referenced in the "Close question -> off topic because... -> Questions asking for help identifying a game... Do not work:

"this [blog post](http://this%20blog%20post%20might%20help) might help" (I am aware of the closure of the blogs)

"We allow an exception for [identifying games based on an actual piece of the game](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5081)"

Comment: Regardless of which comes first, answering questions you know are off-topic is actively detrimental to site health.  You've just signalled that off-topic questions can get an answer, which can lead to more of them being posted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image: Why don't we have both?]

- Tell the user "sorry but no"
- If you are so inclined and know the answer, maybe leave it in the comments as a courtesy?
- Otherwise, if you so desire, link to other places where they can get help
- Finally, vote to close and walk away

Then you can have rules *and* helpfulness.

Comment: The only reason I opted for an answer rather than a comment is rep....

Comment: Rep that you will lose as soon as the question gets deleted.

Comment: @ИвоНедев what comes first? Rules or Rep? You can get a lot of rep by asking/answering on-topic stuff aswell, you know... (Rules come first btw)